How to get absolute position of a view to use for an overlay?
I am trying to create a blurred overlay of a whole screen. I would like to recreate partial elements of the screen on top of the blurred portion to create the effect that everything is blurred except for the chosen elements.
In the example I'm providing, I would like to blur everything except the text "Bye".
The way I am doing this is by using two boxes. One for the main content and the other for the overlay. I keep track of the global position of the "Bye" text using onGloballyPositioned and re-create the view in the overlay using these coordinates.
The problem I am facing is that the coordinates returned seem to be wildly incorrect. None of the values seem useful to me. I am at a loss of how to approach this problem. In testing my real scenario, I have found the values returned using onGloballyPositioned are 2.8 times larger than they should be, but that constant changed across devices.
package com.example.myapplication

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.offset
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.blur
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.onGloballyPositioned
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.positionInParent
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.positionInRoot
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.positionInWindow
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            var root: Offset by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }
            var parent: Offset by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }
            var window: Offset by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }
            var positionText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
            var blur by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }

            Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize().blur(blur).clickable(onClick = {
                if (blur > 0.dp) {
                    blur = 0.dp
                } else {
                    blur = 4.dp
                }
            })) {
                Column {
                    Text(text = "Hi")
                    Text(text = "Hi")
                    Text(text = "Hi")
                    Text(text = "Hi")
                    Text(text = "Hi")
                    Text(text = "Bye", modifier = Modifier.onGloballyPositioned {
                        root = it.positionInRoot()
                        parent = it.positionInParent()
                        window = it.positionInWindow()
                        positionText = "positionInParent: $parent\npositionInRoot: $root\npositionInWindow: $window"
                    })
                    Text(text = "Hi")
                    Text(text = "Hi")
                    Text(text = "Hi")
                    Text(text = positionText)
                }
            }

            Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.offset(x = root.x.dp, y = root.y.dp),
                    text = "Byeeeeeeeeeeeee",
                    color = Color.Blue
                )
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.offset(x = parent.x.dp, y = parent.y.dp),
                    text = "Byeeeeeee",
                    color = Color.Green
                )
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.offset(x = window.x.dp, y = window.y.dp),
                    text = "Byeee",
                    color = Color.Magenta
                )
            }
        }
    }
}



Your Box is outside of the column. Also the co-ordinates that you get are in pixels. You would want them in dp considering the density
Code :
@Composable
fun SOBlur() {

    var parent: Offset by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }
    var positionText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var blur by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }

    Box(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().blur(blur).clickable {
            if (blur > 0.dp) {
                blur = 0.dp
            } else {
                blur = 4.dp
            }
        }) {

            Text(text = "Hi")
            Text(text = "Hi")
            Text(text = "Hi")
            Text(text = "Hi")
            Text(text = "Hi")
            Text(text = "Hi")
            Text(text = "Hi")
            Text(text = "Hi")
            Text(text = "Bye", modifier = Modifier.onGloballyPositioned {
                parent = Offset(
                    it.positionInParent().x,
                    it.positionInParent().y
                )
                positionText =
                    "positionInParent: $parent"
            })
            Text(text = positionText)
        }
            Box(Modifier.offset(x = parent.x.pxToDp(), y = parent.y.pxToDp())) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier,
                    text = "Byeeeeeee",
                    color = Color.Green
                )

            }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Float.pxToDp() = with(LocalDensity.current) { this@pxToDp.toDp() }

ScreenShot: I hope this is what you are lookin for on clicking the column gets blurred and the text is shown at that position.


also note: i moved the text inside the box and made column blur. Box has 2 child elements one is the column with textx the other box overlaps it

Noted. My actual use case is a bit more complex and the two box approach makes a little more sense to me for that, while using positionInRoot().

not sure of your actual use case. but if its a list then you can map index to offset so onl;y clicked item text will show overlapping the blurred list below! any wayt the approach is the same!
